# How does this code generate the proper sequence of characters?

Tags: php, math, obfuscation, captcha

The code in question comes from [MathGuard](http://www.codegravity.com/projects/mathguard), a PHP anti-spam CAPTCHA script that requires the user to answer a simple math problem. It displays the digits and operator symbols as 3x5 matrices of random characters. I understand how the code works in the sense that I can follow the code and understand what it's doing; I just don't understand how one would come to this solution.

This function takes an integer that describes one line of the 3x5 matrix and converts it into a line of random characters:

```
function decToBin($dec) {
    $pattern = "123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRTSTUWXYZ";
    $output = "   ";
    $i = 0;
    do {
        if ($dec % 2) {
            $rand = rand() % 34;
            $output { 2 - $i } = $pattern { $rand };
        } else {
            $output { 2 - $i } = " ";
        }
        $dec = (int) ($dec / 2);
        $i++;
    } while ($dec > 0);
    $output = str_replace(" ", "&nbsp;", $output);
    return $output;
}
```

Here are the digit descriptors:

```
$number = array (
    array ( 7, 5, 5, 5, 7 ), // 0
    array ( 2, 6, 2, 2, 7 ), // 1
    array ( 7, 1, 7, 4, 7 ), // 2
    array ( 7, 1, 7, 1, 7 ), // 3
    array ( 4, 5, 7, 1, 1 ), // 4
    array ( 7, 4, 7, 1, 7 ), // 5
    array ( 7, 4, 7, 5, 7 ), // 6
    array ( 7, 1, 1, 1, 1 ), // 7
    array ( 7, 5, 7, 5, 7 ), // 8
    array ( 7, 5, 7, 1, 7 )  // 9
);
```

My question is: **how does one come to this conclusion and method of generation and know that, for example, `7` will generate a full line of random characters, and `5` only the outermost characters?**

Is this just a form of code obfuscation? What makes this method better than, say, storing the digits as a string (`111101101101111` as `0`, for example) and replacing each `1` with a random character?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a simple bitmap to me.

```
7 = 1 1 1
5 = 1 0 1
5 = 1 0 1
5 = 1 0 1
7 = 1 1 1

2 = 0 1 0
6 = 1 1 0
2 = 0 1 0
2 = 0 1 0
7 = 1 1 1
```